# How to Change Visible Property of ASP.NET Control at RunTime in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2008

A Default.aspx page has some controls. Some controls visibility depends upon conditions. Here, what is tend to accomplish is change the visible property at runtime depending upon the conditional value.

Sampel Markup (Default.aspx in Static Mode)

```
<div id="DivBtnImgCopy" runat="server" Visible = "True">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnImgCopy" CssClass="image" ToolTip="Copy Mode" ImageUrl="img/tlb_img_copy.gif" runat="server" OnClientClick="CopyImage(); SelectButton(this,true);return false;" />
</div>
```

What I tried is write a method in code behind file and tried to get value from that method to set visible property to true or false.

CodeBehindFile (Default.aspx.cs)

```
protected bool ShowHideButton()
    {
        bool bStatus = false;
        try
        {
            if (sCondition == "false")
            {
                bStatus = false;
            }
            else if (sCondition == "true")
            {
                bStatus = true;
            }
            return bStatus;
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Sample Markup (Default.aspx in Dynamic Mode)

```
<div id="DivBtnImgCopy" runat="server" visible = "<% =ShowHideButton() %>">
   <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnCopy" ToolTip="Copy Mode" ImageUrl="img/tlb_img_copy.gif"
                                runat="server" />
</div>
```

But, Getting below error:
Cannot create an object of type '**System.Boolean**' from its **string** representation '**<%=ShowHideButton() %>**' for the 'Visible' property.

Any solution or work-around to accomplish this task.
Need Help.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to do it is having your ShowHideButton return a bool instead of a string ; then :

```
 <%
  DivBtnImgCopy.Visible = ShowHideButton();
 %>

<div id="DivBtnImgCopy" runat="server" >
   <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnCopy" ToolTip="Copy Mode" ImageUrl="img/tlb_img_copy.gif"
                            runat="server" />
</div>
```

Cleanest way would be to include `DivBtnImgCopy.Visible = ShowHideButton();` in the prerender event handler of your page

Comment: By using this approach, I got below error: "The ID 'DivBtnImgCopy' is already used by another control." And I check all code, This ID is not used any where else. So, how to overcome this.

Comment: Same error as above ? NB did you notice that I removed the "Visible" attribute on the div

Comment: Yeah, I've notice and tried it without visible attribute in div tag but above error comes again.

Comment: Couldn't this be caused by another call to ShowHideButton() elsewhere on your page ?

Comment: Does the error disappear when you remove the  <%
  DivBtnImgCopy.Visible = ShowHideButton();
 %> ? I don't see why it would come from here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what visible does.
If you want not to render the div at all, you could wrap your  in a <% if %> :

```
<% if(ShowHideButton()) { %>
<div id="DivBtnImgCopy" runat="server">
   <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnCopy" ToolTip="Copy Mode" ImageUrl="img/tlb_img_copy.gif"
                            runat="server" />
</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Got this error by doing this: The ID 'DivBtnImgCopy' is already used by another control.

Comment: mmm weird. Maybe you don't need the id and the runat server in this case.. do you ?